# Can't deallocate memory in my C program

Tags: c

I need your help deallocating memory in below program. I tried as you can see in main, but no success. Can not get how to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
char name[25];
char street[25];
char citystate[25];
char zip[6];
}student;

 typedef student *studinfo;

 /*function prototypes*/
 void getinfo(student *details[], int *);

 int main(void)
{

int count = 0;
student *studptr[49];

getinfo(studptr, &count);/*call getinfo function to get student info*/


/*int i = 0;
for (i; i<count; i++) {

    free(studptr[i]->name);
    free(studptr[i]->street);
    free(studptr[i]->citystate);
    free(studptr[i]->zip);
   } */

   return 0;
  }
```

Below is a function to get the info from the file. I will use this info later on in sort function and in display function to display the results. After that I should deallocate the memory.

```
void getinfo(student *details[], int *count)
{

char s[100];
studinfo info;

/*Get student information*/
while (gets(s) != NULL) {
    info = (studinfo)malloc(sizeof(student));
    strcpy(info->name, s);
    gets(info->street);
    gets(info->citystate);
    gets(info->zip);


    details[(*count)++] = info; /*Increase the pointer to next position*/

    } /* End of while loop*/

     } /* End of getinfo */
```

Comment: You can only `free()` something that was allocated with `malloc()`.

Comment: More specifically you only need to free when you malloc.  Was it Bob Marley who said "no malloc, no free"?  Variables declared within curly brackets are on the stack (without malloc) and get automatically dumped on returning/break/completion.  If you only need a buffer for the duration of a function or loop, malloc is a waste, but returning a struct, union or pointer to something local is appropriate use of *alloc functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

- You are trying to free components of `struct student`. Since these component arrays were not allocated with `malloc`, you cannot free them; you need to free only the `struct` itself.
- You are using `gets`, which can cause buffer overruns. You should use `fgets` instead, passing buffer size, and `stdin` for the `FILE*` parameter.
- You copy `s[100]` into `info->name`. This can potentially overrun the buffer, because `info->name` fits only 25 characters.

Once you fix these issues, your program should run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    free(studptr[i]);
}
```

Since you allocated each `student` as a single block, you free them the same way.