# Problems with reading and writing from file to file in C

Tags: c

I need your help to point out what I am doing wrong with reading a file and writing to another file. The problem is I don't get anything in my output file where result should be written. Currently modifing my programm [Can't deallocate memory in my C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134426/cant-deallocate-memory-in-my-c-program?noredirect=1#comment42769794_27134426). Now I should use command line arguments to read and write and so far  no success. I think I have an error in my function but don't know how to fix it. Here goes my struct def and  main() func

```
typedef struct{
char name[25];
char street[25];
char citystate[25];
char zip[6];
}student;

   typedef student *studinfo;
```

---

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE *fp1, *fp2; /* file pointer */

        /* see if correct number of command line arguments */
        if (argc != 3) {
            printf("Something wrong with arguments\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* open file for input */
        if ((fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open file to read \n");
            exit(1);
        }

        fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");

        int count = 0;
        student *studptr[49];

        getinfo(studptr, &count, fp1);/*call getinfo function to get student info*/

        sortit(studptr, count); /*call sortit function to sort info based on zip code*/

        result(studptr, &count, fp2); /*call result function to display sorted result*/

        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);

        return 0;
    }
```

and my function that should read info from file and where I suspect my errors are

```
    void getinfo(student *details[], int *count, FILE *fp1)
    {

        studinfo info;

        /*Get student information*/
        while (fp1 != NULL) {
            info = (studinfo)malloc(sizeof(student));
            fgets(info->name, 40,fp1);
            fgets(info->street, 40,fp1);
            fgets(info->citystate,40,fp1);
            fgets(info->zip, 40, fp1);

            details[(*count)++] = info; /*Increase pointer to next position*/

        } /* End of while loop*/

    } /* End of getinfo */
```

I have a function to sort info based on zip code  and the next function to write sorted result to a new file which is presented below

```
    void result(student *details[], int *count,  FILE *fp2)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<(*count); i++) {

            fprintf(fp2,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", details[i]->name, details[i]->street, details[i]->citystate, details[i]->zip); /* print info*/
            fprintf(fp2, "*******************************\n");
        }
    } /* End of result*
```

Comment: why no check for `fp2`? also do you really want `typedef student *studinfo;` and not `typedef student studinfo;` ? also, you din't show us the containts of the file to read from.

Comment: You structure defines the fields of size 25 (except for the zip code which is 6); your `fgets()` calls assume the size is 40.  You will not be happy if someone enters more than 24 bytes of data.  Use `fgets(info->name, sizeof(info->name), fp1)` and equivalent.  Also, check for EOF (the return value of `fgets()` is NULL on EOF). Also note that `fgets()` includes the newline in the data; you may not want that.

Comment: In the previous comment, I noted: _Also note that `fgets()` includes the newline in the data; you may not want that_. I should have added: … not least because you can only store a 4-digit zip code, plus the newline, plus the null in a 6 character array.  You might do better reading the strings into a (large) array: `char buffer[4096];` and `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp1);` and then check the length of the input, zap the newline, and worry about overlong zip-codes.  Remember, `strncpy()` does not null-terminate strings that are too long.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Content of the file looks like this
1st line  John, Doe
2nd line  20294 Street Dr
3rd line  City, State
4th line  91364
few more in a column one after another with different zip codes.

I changed the field sizes, so far no luck.

Comment: `while (fp1 != NULL) {` : Infinite loop.

Comment: I tried  `while (fgetc(fp1) != EOF) {`: didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
int get_line(FILE *fp, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char line[4096];
    assert(buflen > 1);
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) == 0)
        return EOF;
    size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (line[len-1] == '\n')
        line[--len] = '\0';
    if (len >= buflen)
        len = buflen - 1;
    memmove(buffer, line, len);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    return len;
}

void getinfo(student *details[], int *count, FILE *fp)
{
    student *info;

    while ((info = malloc(sizeof(*info)) != 0)
    {
        if (get_line(fp, info->name, sizeof(info->name)) == EOF ||
            get_line(fp, info->street, sizeof(info->stree)) == EOF ||
            get_line(fp, info->citystate, sizeof(info->citystate)) == EOF ||
            get_line(fp, info->zip, sizeof(info->zip)) == EOF)
        {
            free(info);
            return;
        }
        details[(*count)++] = info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `while (fp1 != NULL) {` : Infinite loop. – BLUEPIXY

That's indeed the main problem.

> I tried `while (fgetc(fp1) != EOF) {`: didn't work

That doesn't work right because `fgetc()` consumes a character that is afterwards missing.

You could use the following, with the bonus of discarding spaces before the *name*:

```
        while (fscanf(fp1, "%*[ ]") != EOF)
        {
            …
```